# How to insert different text message in HTML with an event listner attached to radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, event-listener

I'm a new student to javascript, and wrote below code that was meant to display different image and text message based on radio button selection:

```
*<!-- charSelect.html -->*
<!-- skipped -->
<body>
  <img id = "charImg" src = "1.jpg" width = "500" height = "500" border = "0">
  <div id = "charStat">
  </div>
  <div id = "charSelect">
    <form method = "get" action = "form-action.html">
      <input type = "radio" name="char" value = 0>Warrior<br>
      <input type = "radio" name="char" value = 1>Magician<br>
      <input type = "radio" name="char" value = 2>Healer<br>
      <p>
        <input type = "submit" value="OK">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="js/charSelect.js"></script>
```

---

```
*// charSelect.js*
let char0 = `img/01.jpg`;
let char1 = `img/02.jpg`;
let char2 = `img/03.jpg`;
let char3 = `img/04.jpg`;

const imgArray = [ char0, char1, char2, char3, ];

const statWarrior = { class: `Warrior`, level: 1, hp: 1200, en: 300, }
const statMagician = { class: `Magician`, level: 1, hp: 800, en: 560, }
const statHealer = { class: `Healer`, level: 1, hp: 900, en: 410, }

const printStat = document.getElementById(`charStat`);
const radio = document.querySelectorAll(`input[type = "radio"]`);

function charChange(a) {
  document.images[0].src = imgArray[a];
  document.images[0].width = 500;
  switch (a) {
    case 0:
      printStat.textContent = JSON.stringify(statWarrior);
      break;
    case 1:
      printStat.textContent = JSON.stringify(statMagician);
      break;
    case 2:
      printStat.textContent = JSON.stringify(statHealer);
      break;
    default:
      printStat.textContent = `Please select your character.`;
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
  radio[i].addEventListener(`click`, function (e) {
    charChange(e.target.value)
  });
}
```

[Issue]:
When I click different radio buttons, image changes as intended.  However, text message does not change but only shows the default message *"Please select your character"* instead.  I am guessing that the `switch (a)` parameter is not receiving `e.target.value` for some reason, but there is no error message in the console.

[What I tried]:

1. Split the `charChange(a)` function into two separate functions (one
   for image change, the other for text change) -- didn't work out;
2. Change `switch` into `if-else` -- didn't work out.

[Expected behavior]:
The intention is to make both image and text message change together, with the text message displaying the `statWarrior`, `statMagician`, `statHealer` objects.

As I just started learning, I would be happy to take any other comments or suggestions to improve that goes beyond my question above.

Thank you for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.target.value returns a string but the cases expect integers.
You can either turn *a* into an integer or do what I did below and have the cases expect strings.

```
function charChange(a) {
    document.images[0].src = imgArray[a];
    document.images[0].width = 500;
    switch (a) {
        case '0':
            printStat.textContent = JSON.stringify(statWarrior);
            break;
        case '1':
            printStat.textContent = JSON.stringify(statMagician);
            break;
        case '2':
            printStat.textContent = JSON.stringify(statHealer);
            break;
        default:
            printStat.textContent = `Please select your character.`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Changing condition parameters under `switch` to strings like `'0'` , `'1'`, `'2'` worked well and resolved my probelm.  I also tried to change `e.target.value` into numbers using `Number(e.target.value)` and it also worked.  Thank you for your advice.